# Plugin to remove ads

Tags: javascript, jquery, ads

is there any plugin/function out there to remove ads? I know I can use adblock, but I was wondering if there's a simple/naive implementation I can use to programmatically remove ads from a page.

Thanks.

Comment: This article outlines how to remove ads from various browsers http://dottech.org/17516/block-ads-in-firefox-internet-explorer-chrome-and-opera-how-to/ but it does so with using adblock. It would be interesting to have a jquery plugin you can put to remove ads. Can you describe what you are doing in a little more detail? Are you consuming a page which has adverts?

Comment: @Farax sure, I also opened this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564924/ads-filtering-server-side that's a server side approach but now I'm also considering a client side solution, thanks!

Comment: @Farax btw, thanks for sharing the article, but in my case I would need to be able to programmatically trigger the filtering task =/.